# Diagnostic tools not working (VS 2015 Update 2 RTM)

Tags: visual-studio, debug-diagnostic-tool

I have an issue: 
So I'm trying to profile my UWP / Metro (Win8.1) Apps. And keep facing the very same problem, - Diagnostic tools just won't work (Memory Usage specifically).

I keep getting errors like this:

"Failed to enable stack collection on heap trace session (0x8007007f)."

CPU usage turns on, but then it says: "Microsoft Visual Studio was unable to create a diagnostics report."
Would anyone explain me why is this happening and what are the possible workarounds?
Thank you in advance for your time spent to provide me with the solution!

P.S. I've been suffering from for ages and failed to find out how to tackle this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Update 2 RTM for Visual Studio 2015 helped me out!